# Laravel 5 Writing Custom Database Driver

Tags: database, laravel-5, driver

I'm working on project and need to implement custom database driver, but can't find any guidelines which interfaces i should to implement. 
Is there any resourses available that could help writing custom driver rather thank just diving in code and trying to figure out how current drivers are implemented?

**EDIT**

By saying "driver" i mean support for example NoSQL dabase using standart Laravel's methods ( Eloquent model and Query builder ), for example:

```
User::take(10)->get();
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by custom driver? Alternative SQL grammar? Different RDBMS that is currently not supported by Laravel or PDO?

Comment: Please see question update.

Answer (score 2):

For Mysql Laravel uses eloquent
[laravel - eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)

For NoSql like MongoDB, you can use laravel-mongodb
[jenssegers - laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

It's even support Hybrid relations between MySql and MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on MongoDB (a NoSQL database) in one of my project, where I have to use a jenssengers package https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb to use the functionalities. I was not able to use Eloquent in that.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel - eloquent/ jenssegers - Laravel-MongoDB can manage hybrid relations as well.